# jquery animate() problem (syntax ?)

Tags: jquery, jquery-lint

```
$('#somediv').stop(false, true)
             .animate({marginLeft: '-=' + e.width() + 'px'}, options.speed, function(){ options.onNewSlide() })
```

- `e.with()` returns 640
- `options.speed` contains 800
- `options.onNewSlide()` contains a a custom callback function

It works fine in Firefox. But i debugged it with jQuery-Lint because it was throwing some random error in IE. Lint tells me:

```
When I called animate(...) with your args, an error was thrown! TypeError: c.speed is not a function { message="c.speed is not a function",  more...}
You passed:  [Object {  marginLeft="-=640px"}, 800, function()]
```

and it indicates me the line i have posted. 
I have checked the jQuery doc, but my syntax seams ok.

Do you know what I am doing wrong?

PS: I use jQuery 1.4.2 from the Google API you can see the error here: http://meodai.ch/slider/ (I know the code is under construction, but still)

edit:
I have tried to reproduce my error in a new file with just the animation: http://meodai.ch/slider/index2.html there it works very well! Now I am lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you have:

```
options = $.extend(defaultOptions, options)
```

When `options` is `undefined`, this extends the jQuery object with the properties from `defaultOptions`.

Within `defaultOptions` are `speed` and `easing` properties, which overwrite jQuery's internal properties of the same names, causing the error.

A safer way to combine `defaultOptions` and `options` would be:

```
options = $.extend({}, defaultOptions, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing that I see is that you are not specifying the easing function to use. Try

```
$('#somediv')
  .stop(false, true)
  .animate({marginLeft: '-=' + e.width() + 'px'}, 
    options.speed, 
    'linear',
    function(){ options.onNewSlide() })
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made an object `options` for my params. inside the option object i had `speed:` and `easing:` as soon as i renamed that options my problem was solved. But how does it comes that i don't have the same problem on my other test page?

Comment: For some reason your options object is actually the jQuery object, so the `speed` and `easing` options overrode jQuery's properties.

Comment: I think it's this line `options = $.extend(defaultOptions, options)`. In your code, `options` (the argument for `slider()`) is `undefined`, and I think jQuery interprets the extend as `$.extend(defaultOptions)`, which extends and returns the jQuery object. I suggest changing this to `options = $.extend({}, defaultOptions, options);`

Comment: wow, thx a lot. You are right. Please formulate an answer to this post with this. So i can give you a point and marking it as the right answer.